# Airflow use case

Tags: python, airflow

I have a question about for what to use airflow for with our current system.

I have an api which, by using GCP Cloud Tasks, trigger some tasks like sending a welcome email after 2 days and sending useful notifications. This is all in our main api repo.

Now I want for example add 1) a profile image face detector and notify users about the use of a non facial profile image. 2) multiple marketing reminder emails etc 3) classification of user profiles based on their data and 4) a lot more of these kind of background tasks as we grow

It feels weird to put all this extra logic and tasks in the main api repo, trigger it with cloud tasks/cloud scheduler etc is not exactly a good idea. Especially since some tasks can be reused/linked together. Also Cloud Tasks are just http calls but scheduled/delayed and the monitoring is not really intuitive.

So would Airflow be a good solution to manage these tasks and be future proof as our system/business needs besides the api grow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For workloads that are scheduled at a certain time, Cloud Composer (Airflow) can be used and you can link your tasks together which enables you to re-run the failed tasks only. So, if you have certain reports based on user's data as you mentioned to be ready at a certain time, Airflow would be a perfect case for you.
- For workloads that you expect to run within a certain time but it's not guaranteed or it's based on a condition. In your case, if you want to send a reminder to a user only if they haven't updated their expired data for example. Airflow provides you with [Sensors](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/sensors.html) that can monitor a certain service or change and trigger your dag accordingly. Using sensors, you can monitor an X change every day from 11 till 12 (timeout 1 hour) and if the change you are waiting for occurs, then the rest of the tasks would get executed.
- If you have an event-based workload, you can still use Airflow to chain the operations required to be done. However, you need to use additional services to catch such events and trigger your Dag accordingly. Face detector image in your case can be an example here.

  - If the uploaded images are stored in GCS, then you can spin up a Cloud Function that would get triggered by the change in the bucket and fire a trigger to Cloud Composer to execute your Dag. You can also provide additional parameters to your Cloud Function or Dag based on the event you have. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/triggering-with-gcf) explains the case here in a detailed manner.
  - If the change done by the user publishes a message to a Pub/Sub topic, then you can trigger a couple of services like Cloud Run, Cloud Function, Vertex AI pipeline, etc to do the job required. If chaining is required too, you can use Cloud Function to trigger your Dag.

In general, you can use Airflow in a variety of use cases achieving the requested output. Also, chaining in Airflow helps you to re-run failed tasks without re-running the whole dag. This helps in reducing the execution time of your services and therefore cost. Additionally, GCP has a wide set of services that you can use for event-based triggers which helps you in scheduled independent use cases. I'm sharing a couple of examples below.

Resources:

- [Execute Cloud Composer with Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/triggering-gcf-pubsub)
- [Trigger Cloud Functions with Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub)
- [Trigger Cloud Run with Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub)
- [Trigger Vertex AI with Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/trigger-pubsub)

Comment: Thanks for the very clear and helpful explanation. We want to be as independent as possible from all GCP specific tech. So will probably go with triggers from within our API to Airflow. Thanks again. Great answer.